# Whats wrong with my typeahead,js example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I tried to put together my own example for typeahead.js (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and for some reason I can't get it to work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A8P3C/

I have my JSON included and it should be loading from the "local" call in the source.

```
<div class="example example-degrees">
<h2 class="example-name">Degrees</h2>

    <div class="demo">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="degrees">
     </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.countries .typeahead').typeahead({
name: 'degrees',
local: ["Bachelor of Science","Bachelor of Science in Accounting","Bachelor of Science in Business","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Accounting","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Administration","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Communications","Bachelor of Science in Business\/e-Business","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Finance","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Global Business Management","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Green and Sustainable","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Green and Sustainable Enterprise Management","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Hospitality Management","Bachelor of Science in Business\/Human Resource Management"]
 });
```

I thought I could just setup a quick example but I can't get it to work

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed closed brackets for `.ready` and its callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.example-countries .typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'countries',
    local: ["Bachelor of Science",
            "Bachelor of Science in Accounting",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Accounting",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Administration",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Communications",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/e-Business",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Finance",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Global Business Management",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Green and Sustainable",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Green and Sustainable Enterprise Management",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Hospitality Management",
            "Bachelor of Science in Business\/Human Resource Management"]
  }); // <-- add missing closing bracket for ready().
```

And the `typeahead.js` file that you included is incorrect because it's plain text.

You should link to [this file](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js).

[Here is the your updated jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8P3C/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple

Comment: It seems the jsFiddle no longer functions? :(

Answer (score 1):

Checking the console for error. The script you added to the fiddle cannot be loaded:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/master/src/typeahead.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

So change it to this one: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/A8P3C/5/